# arranging elements in to a hash array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, recursion, hash

I am trying to break a javascript object in to small array so that I can easily access the innerlevel data whenever I needed.

I have used recursive function to access all nodes inside json, using the program

http://jsfiddle.net/SvMUN/1/

What I am trying to do here is that I want to store these in to a separate array so that I cn access it like

```
newArray.Microsoft= MSFT, Microsoft;
newArray.Intel Corp=(INTC, Fortune 500);
newArray.Japan=Japan
newArray.Bernanke=Bernanke;
```

Depth of each array are different, so the ones with single level can use the same name like I ve shown in the example Bernanke. Is it possible to do it this way?

Comment: What should happen to the count?

Comment: Count is not needed in the newly created array.. just require the term s

Comment: `"OnelevelTestData"` against `"CentralBankRelated"` does not match the scheme. Are you sure this is the right data? If yes, what should happen to it?

Comment: Im sorry ...that was a mistake... http://jsfiddle.net/SvMUN/2/ IVe updated it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you reduce the `Facets` to a string named `html` - but you want an object.

```
function generateList(facets) {
    var map = {};
    (function recurse(arr) {
        var join = [];
        for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            var current = arr[i].term; // every object must have one!
            current = current.replace(/ /g, "_");
            join.push(current);  // only on lowest level?
            if (current in arr[i]) 
                map[current] = recurse(arr[i][current]);
        }
        return join;
    })(facets)
    return map;
}
```

[Demo on jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/SvMUN/5/)

To get the one-level-data, you could just add this else-statement after the if:

```
            else
                map[current] = [ current ]; // create Array manually
```

Altough I don't think the result ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SvMUN/6/)) makes much sense then.

Comment: I was thinking abt somthng like {
    "Microsoft": [
        "MSFT",
        "Microsoft"
    ],
    "Intel Corp": [
        "(INTC, Fortune 500)"
    ],
    "Germany": [
        "Germany"
    ],
    "Japan": [
        "Japan"
    ],
    
    "Bernanke": [
        "Bernanke"],
       "Fed":[ "Fed"],
        "Federal Reserve":["Federal Reserve"]}
is that possible?? because for oneLevelTestData, the depth is different

Comment: But that means `oneLevelTestData` is a different schema? I don't think you should mix them.

Comment: yes.. the depth is different, so incase its only single level then is it possible to add the same data inside the array also.. If its possible, it wd really helpful..

Comment: I knw the result wont make much sense..bt I can access the relevant data using this result..

Comment: I have one more doubt, in our output, if we giv alert(test.Microsoft); it gives undefined instead of giving two answrs "MSFT",
        "Microsoft"  like test.Microsoft[0]=MSFT and test.Microsoft[1]=Microsoft... why is it like that?